# illegal parameter number biblatex

Tags: biblatex, errors

Hello I am having some issues with bibtex. Not sure what could be wrong. I used these parameters before and the citation is exported.

I am getting the following errors / warnings:

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \NewValue. }
Illegal parameter number in definition of \abx@field@abstract. \endentry
Illegal parameter number in definition of \abx@field@abstract. ...raphy[heading=bibintoc,title={Literature}]
Using fall-back BibTeX(8) backend:(biblatex) functionality may be reduced/unavailable.
'firstinits' option is deprecated.
Citation 'x' on page 1 undefined
There were undefined references.
Please (re)run BibTeX on the file(s):(biblatex) doc(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

bibfile.bib

```
@Article{x,
AUTHOR = {An Author},
TITLE = {A title},
JOURNAL = {A journal},
VOLUME = {42},
YEAR = {1999},
NUMBER = {7},
ARTICLE-NUMBER = {9000},
URL = {https://www.example.com/},
ISSN = {1234-5678},
ABSTRACT = {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.},
DOI = {12.3456/whatever}
}
```

doc.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
    
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=alphabetic,
hyperref=true,natbib=true,
backref=true,backrefstyle=three,
sortcites=true,
maxbibnames=50,
maxcitenames=3,
firstinits=true,
%   refsection=part,
%   refsegment=chapter,
isbn=false,url=true,doi=false]
{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\bibliography{bibfile}

\begin{document}

\cite{x}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Literature}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @daleif done, sorry didn't know better.

Comment: Please replace the command `\bibliography{bibfile}` with `\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}` `\bibliography` command is used to print the bibliogrphy inside the document environment.... I am not sure if there is an alias too for this command in `biblatex` but the usual way for biblatex is to use `\addbibresource` command instead of `\bibliogrpahy` (that is the command of printing the bibliography with `bibtex` and not used with `biblatex` as far as I know)

Comment: I did not manage to reproduce the errors shown at the top with the example entry and document provided here. Can you please double check that the example really reproduces the error (ideally in a new, empty directory, or at least after deleting the `.aux`, `.bbl`, `.log` and `.blg` files). Note that the quoted error messages do not appear to be the full messages from the `.log` file, they appear to be a digest obtained via some tool. Sometimes tools hide important bits of the error messages, so looking at and copying from the `.log` file directly is recommended.

Comment: From the error messages my first guess would be unescaped special characters in the `abnstract` field, e.g. an unescaped `#` or `%`, but without an example that reproduces the error that is just speculation.

Comment: You are right @moewe before I replaced the abstract with lorem ipsum, there was an unescaped #. I removed the abstract since I have no intention of using it in the bibliography. This resolved the issue. Thank you!